# Automation of Uploading of videos to Youtube using frontend and python

Tags: javascript, python, automation, google-api, youtube

I am trying to get the video and the thumbnail from the user from the frontend, processing it in the backend and then using google API to upload it to the youtube.
but i am facing issue with the MediaFileUpload() function which requires the path of the video to upload it to the Youtube.

**is there any other way to upload video not using MediaFileUpload() in python?**

without my front end, if I try to upload using MediaFileUpload() with the coded path of the video it is uploading the video to the Youtube.

from the frontend the video is converted to blob and then send to the backend which sends the video the google API.

**code**:

```
videoBlob = new Blob([document.getElementById("video").files[0]], {type: videoFileType});
imageBlob = new Blob([document.getElementById("image").files[0]], {type: imageFileType});
```

please help me to find the alternative for the MediaFileUpload() in python

Comment: Can you add more code sample of how you tried using MediaFileUpload and the error you got when you did it

Comment: @Brett
please visit the link for the code 
https://notepad.pw/youtubeAPI

Comment: @Brett my error :

leapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2Cstatus&alt=json returned "Request contains an invalid argument.". Details: "[{'message': 'Request contains an invalid argument.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'badRequest'}]"

Comment: videoFileType = document.getElementById("video").files[0].type
  imageFileType = document.getElementById("video").files[0].type // This needs to be "image" not "video"

Comment: Put the code into the question as well. not in a separate place